# Why is there a pause between a back-to-back println and print statement?

Tags: rust

I am writing a simple HTTP request using the standard libraries `net` module:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let request = 
b"GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

";

    let mut response = String::new();

    print!("Connecting...");
    let mut stream = net::TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080")
        .expect("Cannot connect to server");
    println!("Connected!");

    print!("Writing...");
    stream.write(request)
        .expect("Error writing");
    println!("Written!");

    print!("Reading...");
    stream.read_to_string(&mut response)
        .expect("Error reading");
    println!("Read!");

    println!("\nResponse:\n{}", response);
    Ok(())
}
```

I have a simple [Express](https://expressjs.com/) webserver running locally on `localhost:8080`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.time('/')
  res.send('ok')
  console.timeEnd('/')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server on ${port}`))
```

When I run the program, there is a second or two pause between the printing of `Written!` and `Reading...`. Why does that pause occur when there seems to be nothing there to pause execution?

Server Output:

```
/: 5.168ms
```

Rust Output:

```
Connecting...Connected!
Writing...Written! // PAUSES HERE AT EOL!
Reading...Read!

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-eoX0dku9ba8cNUXvu/DyeabcC+s"
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2018 22:32:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

ok
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdout` is typically line buffered, meaning it stores whatever you write to it in a buffer until it sees a newline. So you won't see anything until `println!("Read!");` prints a newline.

If you want to display the contents before that you need to [flush the buffer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush).

```
use std::io;  // for io::stdout

...

print!("Reading...");
io::stdout().flush()?;
```

Comment: That was it.. Thank you for your help!